# Make cookies work with PhoneGap in iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, cookies, cordova

I'm trying to make persistant cookies work with PhoneGap and iOS5 and can't get it to persist beyond hard close of the app. The often-documented method of adding

```
//special setting to accept cookies via ajax-request
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage 
                                      sharedHTTPCookieStorage]; 
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

doesn't work in iOS5, or maybe I'm just not sure the right place to put it.  I'm using Cordova 1.8.1.

If relevant, I'm using code similar to this for persistant storage: https://gist.github.com/3243819

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better idea to use PhoneGap's device storage methods, see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 0):

Apparently iOS 5 disables Cookies by default